# Не выходит подключить fop  к проекту

Tags: java, linux

Добрый день! Появилась необходимость в написании приложения на `java` формирующего `pdf`-документы. В найденном примере содержались строки:

```
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;
```

Oднако, `netbeans` утверждает, что "`package does not exist`". Пробовал установить `classpath` следующим образом:

```
java -cp /usr/share/maven-repo/org/apache/xmlgraphics/fop/1.0/fop-1.0.jar
```

Oднако никакого эффекта это не повлекло, хотя `apache fop` установлен и из командной строки работает. Подскажите, будьте добры, каким образом разрешить данную ситуацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Oднако, netbeans утверждает, что
> "package does not exist".

и правильно утверждает, поскольку для Netbeans'а надо декларировать вашу библиотеку

1. Положите ваш jar в каталог ./lib
2. Топчем tools->library
3. Задаем вашу либу классы которой указывают на ваш jar лежащий в ./lib
4. Указываем в зависимостях прожекта что надо включить созданную либу

**P.S.** Читайте документацию Netbeans!

Comment: Всё получилось, огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

[findJar](http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=org.apache.fop.apps.Fop)

и тд по списку.. =)

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что мне с этим делать. Я нашёл по данной ссылке файл fop-0.95-1.jar, выполнил в командной строке 
java -cp /home/onedrop/javaproj/classes/fop-0.95-1.jar, однако ничего не изменилось. Верен ли синтаксис подключения classpath?

Comment: лучше найти в netbeans как к проекту цеплять либы..

Comment: хорошая мысль, попробую